# Post from Form to Channel

Tags: channel-form, forms

We're developing a form where the user submits a large form - 40 fields plus - which needs to get mailed to two different admins (one with the actual content and one with some other information) but which **ALSO** needs to post to a channel.

As of now we're looking at using Channel:Form and a Postmaster/Notification add on. But am wondering if this is actually the best way. Is there perhaps a more efficient approach using a form-submission module - one that submits the form and also posts to a channel?

Is there such a module? Any tips on how others might approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is a good one if you're form is inserting/updating a single channel at a time. I'm doing the same thing with channel form handling the form and [Postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) for the notifications (here's an example from the [Postmaster docs](https://www.objectivehtml.com/postmaster/utilities/email-endpoint)).

Comment: Cool, I was looking at Postmaster - is it a good notification solution do you think? Can it mail the Channel entry like it was a form submission?